# How to return an int to another class

Tags: java, return, return-value

I'm trying to learn how to use variables from 1 class in another one. What the first class does is that it sets the int testInt to 0 and once a value is inserted in the textField and then pressed the button it is changing the value to that number. But here is the problem, when I try to use the variable in the other class I print out a 0 instead of the number i typed.

First class that creates the variable and should change it too.

```
public class RouletteGui extends JPanel {
        private JTextField tfInput = new JTextField();
        private JPanel center = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        private JPanel South = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        private JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Change int value");

    private int testInt = 0;
    public RouletteGui() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

        center.add(tfInput, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(South, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        South.add(btnSearch, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        center.add(tfInput, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        createListeners();

    }
    public void createListeners() {
        button b = new button();
        btnSearch.addActionListener(b);
    }

    private class button implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == btnSearch) {
                testInt = Integer.parseInt(tfInput.getText());
                System.out.println(testInt);
            }else{}
        }

    }
    public int getTestInt(){
        return testInt;
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Kalkylator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new RouletteGui());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Second class that will write out the int.

```
public class WritingInt {
    private RouletteGui rg = new RouletteGui();
    public WritingInt(){
        System.out.println(rg.getTestInt());
    }
    public static void main (String args[]){
        WritingInt wi = new WritingInt();
    }

}
```

Comment: Short answer: change the visibility of your variable. Long answer: don't do this. Do **not** learn a new programming language and at the same time try to build UI applications. That's like learning to juggle ... whilst learning to ride the unicycle at the same time. First: learn the essential java basics (like: visibility of fields) ... and when you mastered all those little things; start building your UI programs. That sounds boring, but is much more efficient and will lead to **working** programs much quicker. Finally: do some prior research next time. You are **not** the first beginner here

Comment: What does print 0, `System.out.println(rg.getTestInt());` or `System.out.println(testInt);`? In the former case that's most probably a threading issue or a setup error (it looks like you don't display the UI in the second main(), see Jägermeister's comment here: first learn the basics then bother with UI), in the latter case it's most likely some setup issue with your UI (I didn't check that but again: learn the basics first).

Comment: System.out.println(rg.getTestInt()); which is stated in the class that doesn't declare the variable. System.out.println(testInt); writes out the correct value which the user inputs and this can only be stated in the class where the variable is declared.

Comment: Of course `System.out.println(rg.getTestInt());` would print 0. Your computer can perform this action much faster than you can enter a number, and you're doing nothing to pause the main thread.

Comment: But I execute the second class after I input the value and press the button? Or that wonät work like that?

Comment: Problem is, you're not executing the main method after you input value and press button. You're executing the main method **after initializing `RouletteGui`**. Because you in no way force the user to enter a value for the main method in order to continue, continue it will.

Comment: Ah I see, how would I change this in the best way?

Comment: Get better at Java then reconsider your design? This is perhaps a more open-ended question than you may realize. Thus the delayed response ... your problem now seems to be escaping the scope of what it is you've asked. There are a number of things here that don't make sense. There is no reason to create an instance of WritingInt in your WritingInt main method(in fact, this will also **create a second RouletteGui** with your current setup).

Comment: There is also no need for two main methods here. Without explicitly calling the second main method it won't even run. Additionally, running both main methods independently will not work as you're working with a completely different set of objects and fields that aren't visible to one another. What you've been saying makes me suspect you may not have realized this. As @Jägermeister says, basics first. You're putting the cart before the horse here. Trying to code before understanding basics is almost guaranteed to result in overly complex and/or nonsensical solutions.